# Django: FormView: How to retain form values after refresh?

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a FormView as follows:

```
class SignUpView(FormView):
   template_name = '/accounts/signup.html'
   form_class = SignUpForm

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      context = super(SignUpView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
      # code..
      return context

   def get_initial(self):
      initial = super( SignUpView, self ).get_initial()
      # code..
      initial = {
         'email':      email,
         'dob_mm':     dob_mm,
         'dob_dd':     dob_mm,
         'dob_yyyy':   dob_yyyy,
         'email_conf': "",
         'password':   "",
      }
      return intial

   def form_valid(self, form):
      # hit external APIs to validate, charge card, etc.
      # if any errors from APIs, return to SignUp form
      messages.error( self.request, errors )
      return redirect('/account/signup/')
```

At this point, if the page is reloaded (due to any errors), the form is re-initialized blank, except for some of the fields I prep in get_initial(). Is there any way to automatically retain the input fields, or would I have to manually store them, detect it's a refresh due to errors, then set all the fields manually in the get_initial()?

I haven't been able to find any posts or docs that would describe how to do it with a FormView. Thanks!

Comment: Why not implement client side validation to filter out the majority of invalid field entries? You can disable the submit button if invalid entries exist, and then rely on server side validation for final processing.

Comment: I do that. The errors I'm referring to can come back from external APIs -- e.g. user already present, payment not successful, etc. -- so I can't check those from the client..

Answer (score 0):

I would implement value storage via cookie and each time a blur event occurs, the element that has just lost focus updates the cookie value.

Then, if form submission fails, the server sets a 'valid-submission' cookie setting to `false`.  If a page refreshes, a javascript function checks for the `valid-submission` setting, and if false, repopulates the fields. Otherwise, the server deletes the cookie setting.

Comment: Thought of something like that but was just curious if Django may have something built-in for that.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You lose all post data when doing a redirect, this has nothing to do with Django. Instead of doing a redirect, you should just render the page if you encounter any errors:

```
class SignUpView(FormView):
    ...

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # check for errors
        if errors:
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form, errors=errors))
        return redirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Better yet would be to keep the logic separated properly, and do the error checking in the form class itself, either in the `clean_<field>` methods for individual fields, or the `clean` method for the whole form.